# How to create custom formula in Salesforce

Tags: formula-field

How can I create a custom formula?

Comment: What do you want this formula to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go on below link and read here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas.